# S3 Bucket Policy with Negate statement ( prinicipalorgid )

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Not able to define bucket policy using "PrincipalOrgID" with negate condition.

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1606557924566",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1606557921184",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::Account_ID:root"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::Bucket_Name/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotEquals": {
                    "aws:PrincipalOrgID": "o-123456"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The above bucket policy does not work and when I try to download an object from the bucket it still shows the `403` error.

The same if I tried policy with `Allow` and `StringEquals` it works.

Any help what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: If you do NOT have the above policy, can you download the object? Note that buckets are private by default and there is no `Allow` policy shown, so the above policy only _removes_ access -- it does not grant access.